# condition in where clause based on a row's id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I'm pretty new to MySQL but am wondering how to do the following:

```
SELECT name from table 
if the id=1 then SELECT name WHERE '%first%'

else if the id in (2,3,4) then SELECT name
```

Basically, I want to check for the string "first" in the name if the id is 1 and don't check for any string if the id is 2, 3, or 4. Is there an easy way to do this? I've only found the IF function but can't use 2 conditions in it. Also, the table has more than just the ids 1,2,3,4 so I can't just say else; I still need to check whether the ids are in (2,3,4).

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `and` and `or`.

```
SELECT name from table 
where (id=1 and name like '%first%') 
or id in (2,3,4)
```

Edit: Based on OP's comment for one more condition that should be applied to id's 1,2,3,4

```
SELECT name from table 
where birthyear=1990 
and ((id=1 and name like '%first%') or id in (2,3,4))
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking but now what if I have a third condition that applies to both if id=1 and id=2,3,4 , such as birthyear = 1990

Comment: dang, perfect. I didn't realize that you can put the similar condition right after the where and add the more specific conditions later. Thanks for the help!